# Seeking some specific information about a 1994 Toyota Hi-Ace

Tags: toyota, emissions, hiace

I am attempting to matriculate my camper from the UK to portugal and in order to do so they have requested what is known as a "certificate of conformity". Unfortunately i cant get one of these because the vehicle was manufactured prior to Jan 1995 and is also originally a japanese import. Instead they are now asking for the following information;

- Cylinder/Displacement
- Type of CO2 tests (WLTP OR NEDC)
- CO2 gas emission (g/km)
- Particles (More OR Less than 0,001 g/km*)

I am really struggling to find this and when i spoke to Toyota UK they told me to contact Toyota Japan so I have hit a dead-end.

Is this information readily available anywhere?

Comment: Even if you find this information somewhere online, you may have trouble getting a formal CofC that would be acceptable to the Portuguese authorities.  Contacting Japan may be your only way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For most of this, I would bet you'd get this through testing, not through what the manufacturer specs say. The only one which would be specs would be cylinder (number of cylinders) and displacement (total displacement of the engine). It should be pretty easy to tell the number of cylinders just through looking at the engine (in most cases). Displacement just became easy, because from what I'm seeing, it came with either 2.8L diesel or 2.4L petrol. While I don't know for sure, I'll bet it's a 4-cyl in either case. You should be able to look at the engine itself and see how many cylinders it has (look at the exhaust manifold and see how many different ports are attached to the head; count the injectors on the diesel; count sparkplug wires on a petrol [there would be an additional one for a coil wire]).

The type of CO2 test would become known when you take it to a testing station. Tell them why you need the test and ask them what type of test they use to get the CO2 emissions. I'm not sure *exactly* what is meant by "Particles" ... could that be *particulate*? Still, even for that a testing station should know exactly what you want and give you the information through testing.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Without knowing what Portuguese law requires (manufacturer info, as I suggested), or current test results (as you suggest)...we're both guessing.

Answer (score 0):

This sort of issue comes up regularly in the US when people try to import vehicles not originally built for the US. The "Certificate of Conformity" (other names are also used) is a statement **from the manufacturer** that at the time the vehicle was built, it conformed to whatever governmental laws and regulations were in force, in the OP's case, in Portugal. It is not a current report about how "clean" the exhaust is.

At least here in the US, the only authority competent to issue such a statement is the vehicle manufacturer. While Toyota UK referred you to Toyota Japan, what you really need to know is **whose declaration will be acceptable to the Portuguese authorities**.

If Portuguese law is different from US law and they'll take an aftermarket tester's report, that'd be easy to obtain as Paulster2 notes in his answer. If, on the other hand, the Portuguese authorities will only accept a manufacturer's statement...then you're going to have to get a statement from Toyota Japan, or change your plans to import the vehicle.